# How do you have a client deployment communicate with the api deployment in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

All I ever get are CORS errors while on localhost and in the cloud. It works if I manually type in localhost or I manually get the service external IP and input that into the k8s deployment file before I deploy it, but the ability to automate this is impossibly if I have to launch the services, get the external IP and then put that into the configs before I launch each time.

API service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: api
  name: api-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080 # expose the service on internal port 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080 # our nodejs app listens on port 8080
  selector:
    app: api # select this application to service
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Client Service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: client
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

API deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: api
  name: api-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mjwrazor/docker-js-stack-api:latest
        name: api-container
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources: {}
        stdin: true
        tty: true
        workingDir: /app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - npm
        - run
        - start
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: server-side-configs
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes: null
      serviceAccountName: ""
status: {}
```

Client Deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: client
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      containers:
      - image: mjwrazor/docker-js-stack-client:latest
        name: client-container
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources: {}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
status: {}
```

I tried adding an ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: http://client-service.default
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api-development.default
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

But didn't help either. here is the server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome" });
});

require("./app/routes/customer.routes.js")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

But like I said I am trying to get this to resolve via the hostnames of the services and not have to use the external IP, is this even possible or did I misunderstand something along the way.

The client sends an axios request. Cannot use environment variables since you can't inject environment variables from k8s after the project is been build through webpack and docker into an image. I did find a really hacky way of creating a file with window global variables and then have k8s overwrite that file with new window variables. But again I have to get the external IP of the api first then do that.

Comment: `host: api-development.default` does not look like a real domain name and without it I don't think this is going to work. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @OhHiMark that is the deployment name. I have used db-service.default `hostname.namespace` to connect the DB to the api. Would this mean I have to buy a domain name before I could even use the automatic dns resolution?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @OhHiMark no, as this is just a practice project I am not going to buy a domain name to get this to work. Plus, the project I am practicing for will not have any domain names for 100s of items, so I will have to learn to get the IP a different way. Maybe Terraform outputs

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will compose an answer based on what we have discussed here just to close this topic and make it more clear for the rest of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments you need to get a real domain name in order to make it work as Automatic DNS resolution in your case basically requires it.